# How to set Font size in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: fonts

I am new to Ubuntu and having issue to set the System font size in 15.04.
Can I set it from System Settings?

OR I have to install tool for it?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the Document fonts, you don't need any other tools. just open the system settings, go to `Text Entry` and there you can change the Font family and the font size. the left bottom corner.

[image]

To change system fonts you need unity-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Open fonts from appearance tab and choose what you want

[image]

#### Another Option to use

you can also use `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Go to `Fonts` tab on the left panel then choose what font to change

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter So whay Downvoting?

Comment: Please be careful with `unity-tweak-tool`, it's not official and can brake Unity so you have to reset everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra tool.

Get the *Unity Tweak Tool*. Open a terminal and install with

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Start it with *Unity Tweak Tool*, click *Fonts* in the category *Appearance* and set the sizes.

Tested on 14.04.

Comment: I agree, tested with 15.04

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Turning-on-off button in the upper right corner of screen, System settings, Display, Scale for menu and tittle bars. Here the scaling factor of entire GUI can be changed. I have tested it in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. I think it will work also in 15.04.

Comment: No, this just changes the size of menus and title bars, but not text in Firefox for example.